# Fedora 18 - changing mount point for Samba share

Tags: network-shares, samba, automount

As from title, how would I go to change the automatic mount point for a Samba share?

By default it is mounted in `/run/user/<UID>/gvfs/smb-share:server=<IP>,share=<label>`

This, however is a bit annoying as certain piece of software I use do not like the comma and colon in the path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mountpoints chosen by Gvfs cannot be changed except by modifying the source code.

If you always need to use the same share, you could create a symlink with a more acceptable name:

```
ln -s $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/smb-share:server=<IP>,share=<label> ~/tmp/mysmbshare
```

Comment: Great, works perfectly!